# Get rows and their count

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I'd like to fetch rows of the given table and get their total number in the same query. How this can be done in the SQLAlchemy?

I've tried:

```
session.query(Model, func.count(Model.id)).all()
```

but it seems that only one record is loaded  to Python even if count is 11.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just the same way you'd find the length of a list:

```
rows = session.query(Model).all()
number_of_rows = len(rows)
```

Comment: `session.query(Model).count()` is more efficient, because it calculates the count on the database-side

Comment: Maybe? :) Single index hit queries-- maybe? ones with joins and filters... maybe not? e.g. is it quicker to run the query twice, one with a `.all()`, one with a `.count()`.  Or just `len()` the one already fetched and in memory.